# UIImagePickerController corrupts image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I'm working on an app and I need to get bytes from an `UIImage`.

For the moment, I use `UIImagePickerController`, and get the `UIImage` like this,

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

and then get data from `UIImage` using this code,

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

However, `data` appears to get corrupted in this case.

On other hand, I have add the jpeg to app's bundle, and tried to convert the image then to data,

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mapa" ofType:@"jpeg"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Surprisingly this works perfectly.

Here are my questions:

1. How can I get the bytes of image selected from `UIImagePickerController` correctly?
2. Is there a way to add photos to the bundle programmatically?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have some metadata bytes on the original JPEG ("GEO-Information").
If i store the jpeg on the ipad, that metadata disappear, and I need them :S

Comment: your need is just to store images in bundle, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to store image in document directory;

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
[data writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```

Here 'data' will be the NSData you have obtained from your image captured.